# visual basic adjust audio volume with a trackbar / slider

Tags: visual-studio-2012, audio, slider, volume, trackbar

i have a program that plays background music by using this code

```
My.Computer.Audio.Play("bgsound.wav", AudioPlayMode.BackgroundLoop)
```

How can i make a TrackBar (or slider) control its volume, and keeping it extremely simple if possible! Thanks

here is what I had in mind on what it would look like

```
Private Sub TrackBar1_Scroll(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TrackBar1.Scroll
    'get the value of trackbar in a variable
    Dim Value = TrackBar1.Value
    My.Computer.Audio.Volume = Value 'i know this doesn't exist. This is what i need to know what to say
End Sub
```

Comment: You can't do that. Use any audio library or the built in `MediaPlayer` class. You generally should avoid using the My.* namespace.

Comment: @thefiloe I completely forgot about the MediaPlayer! I'll check that out, thanks! :D